# Inherited variable doesn't like new values

Tags: scala, variables, inheritance

Could someone explain me why:

```
abstract class Super(var title: String)

class Sub(title: String) extends Super(title) {
    def test = println(title)
}

val s = new Sub("a")
s.test
s.title = "b"
s.test
```

prints:

```
a
a
```

instead of:

```
a
b
```

?

Comment: Arseniy has it right.  Look at your Sub decleration doesn't declare its constructor parameter as a **var**.  Try changing it to `class Sub(var title: String)...` and see the compiler error you get.

Comment: OK, I think it is not intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy. You simply refers to constructor param, not the inherited variable. You may either rename constructor param, or refer to the var with `this.` prefix

```
class Sub(titleP: String) extends Super(titleP) {
    def test = println(title)
}
```

Comment: Aye.  In the original code, a new constructor parameter is shadowing the original at the point where the test method is defined.